# Having trouble to write lambda expression for One to Many Relationship in Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, web-applications

I am trying to extract list of *Categories* with the corresponding *Tickets* for a specific userId using Linq Lambda expression.

Category:

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

Ticket:

```
public class Ticket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public User User { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }
```

User:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what I tried so far, but it is only returns Category if it has any ticket.
I want all Categories with Tickets (for a specific userId)

```
            var query = from cate in _context.Categories.Include(c => c.Tickets)
                        join tickets in _context.Tickets
                        on cate.Id equals tickets.Category.Id
                        where tickets.User.Id.Equals(id)
                        select (cate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DatabaseContext.Categories
                         .Include(c => c.Tickets)
                         .Where(c => c.Tickets.Any(t => t.User.Id.Equals(id)));
```

This may help you and I recommend you to learn more about linq operators first.